# How to find average distance of points in polygon to boundary of polygons?

Tags: point, distance, proximity, boundaries

I have a layer of polygons and a layer of points that I lay on top of those polygons. Some polygons, which I will refer to here as "zones", will contain 1 point within their boundary, and others will contain more than 1 point within their boundary. My map looks like this:

[image]

The points shown above are the centroids of polygons from another layer that is building footprint polygons, each with varying areas. These points accordingly contain values for the area of the building footprints they correspond to. And so the attribute table for the points would look like:

```
ID       Area
--------------
 1         xx 
 2         xx
 3         xx
 4         xx
 5         xx
...
```

For each point, I want to calculate the average distance to the boundary of the zone which it is located within, but I am having a bit of trouble trying to conceptualize and think this through since some zones have more than 1 point within, and also since these zones are uneven shapes, e.g. not circular buffers. , which is why I say "average" distance. Or I am thinking maybe it could be distance to the nearest point that is part of the zone boundary. I want to assign a single "distance to boundary" value for each point. The whole purpose of this is to calculate a single value/factor (or more accurately, a coefficient) that can relate the area of a point to the distance to the boundary of its respective zone.

For zones containing more than 1 point, I am thinking of just finding the distance-to-boundary for both points and just averaging them, and then assigning that same distance-to-boundary value to both points.

The output I want would be a points layer where in the attribute table it would have an ID for each points, with a corresponding area, and a corresponding distance-to-boundary value, like such:

```
ID     Area    Distance_to_boundary
------------------------------------
 1       xx                     xx
 2       xx                     xx
 3       xx                     xx
 4       xx                     xx
 5       xx                     xx     
...
```

I would then export this attribute table as a csv and perform regression analysis to find the relationship between "Area" and "Distance-to-boundary".

Can this be done in QGIS? Or would this be much more complex than I am making it out to be? I am unsure how to proceed with proximity tools, since this a little more complicated than just finding the distance between points.